# Why domains does not catch below exception?

Tags: node.js, node.js-domains

Why domain does not handle below error?

```
var globalDomain = domain.createDomain();

globalDomain.run( function() {
    // Why below exception does not get handled by globalDomain?
    throw "some error"; 
});

globalDomain.on('error', function(msg) {
    console.log("In global error event:" + msg);
});
```

Again, It works perfectly well with below code,

```
var globalDomain = domain.createDomain();

globalDomain.run( function() {
    setTimeout(function(){
        throw "some error from timeout";
    },0);
});

globalDomain.on('error', function(msg) {
    console.log("In global error event:" + msg);
});
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
var globalDomain = domain.createDomain();

globalDomain.on('error', function(msg) {
    console.log("In global error event:" + msg);
});

globalDomain.run( function() {
    //  exception gets handled by globalDomain !!
    throw "some error"; 
});
```